# What actions trigger webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate function

Tags: ios, swift, webview, webkit

I made a iOS app with Xcode and Swift with only a WebView. Sometimes the website, render by that WebView, crash. In this case I want to reload the WebView.

To do that I read that there is a new trigger in iOS 9 who is called when :

> the web view’s web content process is terminated.

Source : [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKNavigationDelegate/webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate:)

So I add this function to my `ViewController` file :

```
func webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate(webView: WKWebView){
    print("Reload");
    self.webView!.reload();
}
```

But when my website crash nothing append, so I wonder: in which case webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate is called ?

Comment: Any update on that ?

Comment: No sorry, I give up :( But I would love to know if someone find the response.

Answer (score 5):

*kristfal* found some interesting behaviors :

> If the app is running in the foreground, crash recovery is working
>   very well via webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate. It simply reloads
>   the wkwebview. No new instance of the webview is created, so no more
>   memory issues (the current implementation is leaking).
>
> When the app is returning from the background, it is prone to crashing
>   the webview without calling webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate. The
>   app will attempt to recover with a reload of the webview via
>   applicationDidBecomeActive, but if it fails (which seems to happen
>   around 1/10 times), it will crash the entire app to prevent getting
>   stuck in an infinite loading loop.

Source : https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView/issues/248#issuecomment-235241805